# how to get 6 months data

Tags: sql, impala, hue

I am running below query in impala but getting error related to unix_timestamp

`AnalysisException: No matching function with signature: unix_timestamp(TIMESTAMP, STRING)`.

Same query while running in hue, I am getting error related to add_months

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 8:28 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'add_months' '(' in expression specification
```

If I run a below separate add_months query, I am able to get the result:

```
select add_months(max(period), -6) from ph_com_b_gbl_sales.it_fact_sales
```

## query :

```
select 
product.brand as product_group,
sum(equivalent_units) as equivalent_units ,
sales.data_source, 
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(period,'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyy-MM')
from (select sales_line, territory_mapping_key from ph_com_b_gbl_sales.it_territory_mapping where sales_line = 'Linea Cardiometabolica') territory_mapping
inner join
(select territory_mapping_key,equivalent_units, sales_office, product_key, data_source, period from ph_com_b_gbl_sales.it_fact_sales where sales_office = 'ITOS' and data_source like '%DPC%' or data_source like'%Ex Factory%' or data_source like '%Sell-out%') sales
on sales.territory_mapping_key = territory_mapping.territory_mapping_key
inner join
(select brand,product_key from ph_com_b_gbl_sales.it_dim_product where brand like '%ENTRESTO%') product
on sales.product_key = product.product_key
where sales.period between (select add_months(max(period), -6) from ph_com_b_gbl_sales.it_fact_sales) and (select max(period) from ph_com_b_gbl_sales.it_fact_sales)
group by sales.data_source,sales.period,product.brand
```

My objective is to fetch the 6months data and that wont be the last 6 months data, I j just have to provide the range of 6 months

Comment: Try giving aliases to your tables and referring alias.column

Comment: Your `AnalysisException` says that `unix_timestamp` function cannot accept arguments of these types, and indeed according to Impala doc possible options are "unix_timestamp(), unix_timestamp(string datetime), unix_timestamp(string datetime, string format), unix_timestamp(timestamp datetime)".

Comment: Also accrding to Impala docs, it supports scalar subqueries in WHERE clauses with comparison, IN and EXISTS only, i.e. BETWEEN is not supported.

Comment: So , any alternatives for the keyword "between"?

Comment: @SanskarSuman BETWEEN = `...where sales.period >= ... and sales.period <= ...`